# Charged Particle

Tags: electric-fields, charge

If a negatively charged particle is traveling anti-parallel to a uniform electric field, will its kinetic energy increase? Is this a valid statement? If not, what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

First, energy is a frame dependent quantity, but if you want to neglect that, **yes, the Kinetic energy increases.** Why? Well, all this would be wrong if we take into account the fact that energy, velocity, acceleration - all of these quantities depend on **who** is measuring them, that is, they are frame dependent. But since we're ignoring it, the particle would accelerate, because the force on the particle would be opposite to the field, and the particle accelerates. Clearly implies it's energy increases.

Also, I've given this answer assuming that the observer is in a frame which is stationary with respect to the particle.

Any corrections to the answer are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will increase because there is a force is acting on the particle. Force means acceleration.

Not only the particle will move in the field but it's velocity will change by $u+\frac{qE}{m}t$ , every second.

$\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$

$m\vec{a}=q\vec{E}$

$\vec{a}=\frac{q\vec{E}}{m}$

From newton's laws,

$\vec{v}=\vec{u}\space +\space \vec{a}t $

Therefore, $\vec{v}=\vec{u}\space +\space \frac{q\vec{E}}{m}t $